# Python: Append Multiple Values for One Key in Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the below list of tuples:

```
p = [("01","Master"),("02","Node"),("03","Node"),("04","Server")]
```

I want my output to look like:

```
y = {
     "Master":{"number":["01"]},
     "Node":{"number":["02", "03"]},
     "Server":{"number":["04"]}
     }
```

I have tried the below code:

```
y = {}
for line in p:
     if line[1] in y:
          y[line[1]] = {}
          y[line[1]]["number"].append(line[0])
     else:
          y[line[1]] = {}
          y[line[1]]["number"] = [line[0]]
```

And I get the below error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
 KeyError: 'number'
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: is it always in ascending order by the first ID??

Comment: @jamylak No not necessarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't initialize your dictionary when needed, and you reset it when not needed.

Try this:

```
p = [("01","Master"),("02","Node"),("03","Node"),("04","Server")]

y = {}
for (number, category) in p:
    if not y.get(category, False):
        # initializes your sub-dictionary
        y[category] = {"number": []}

    # adds the correct number to the sub-dictionary
    y[category]["number"].append(number)
```

Note that using a tuple unpacking `for (number, category) in p` allows your code to be more readable inside your loop.

Comment: This is much more sleek! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for v, k in p:
    d[k]["number"].append(v)


print(d)

  defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f8005097578>, {'Node': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'number': ['02', '03']}), 'Master': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'number': ['01']}), 'Server': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'number': ['04']})})
```

without defaultdict:

```
d = {}
from pprint import pprint as pp
for v, k in p:
    d.setdefault(k,{"number":[]})
    d[k]["number"].append(v)


pp(d)

{'Master': {'number': ['01']},
 'Node': {'number': ['02', '03']},
 'Server': {'number': ['04']}}
```

Comment: If you want to use `defaultdict`, then take full advantage of it: d = `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`. Now all you need to do is: `d[k]["number"].append(v)`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary true, changed

Answer (score 1):

Do not assign {} to key when key is already present in y.

```
y = {}
for line in p:
     try:
          y[line[1]]["number"].append(line[0])
     except:
          y[line[1]] = {}
          y[line[1]]["number"] = [line[0]]
```

OR
Use defaultdict use:-

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> p = [("01","Master"),("02","Node"),("03","Node"),("04","Server")]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in p:
...    d[v].append(k)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Node': ['02', '03'], 'Master': ['01'], 'Server': ['04']})
```

Answer (score 1):

**You are resetting the dictionary!**

```
for line in p:
     if line[1] in y:
          #y[line[1]] = {}   -- RESET! ["number"] will now disappear.
                               #.. which leads to error in the next line.
          y[line[1]]["number"].append(line[0])
     else:
          y[line[1]] = {}
          y[line[1]]["number"] = [line[0]]
```

A more pythonic way of achieving the same thing would be by using a `defaultdict` as demonstrated in other answers.

Comment: Thank you! This works!! I knew I was making a stupid mistake somewhere! Thanks a lot!